# Access 2007 reports, hiding fields?

Tags: ms-access, reporting

I have a report in Access 2007 thats populated with data from SQL SERVER (running on a vb6 application). This report has two subreports that display data. The first Subreport has a Label, *"CHILDREN"* and the subreport next to it displays Names of children. The 2nd subreport has a Label *"PETS"* and the subreport next to it displays PetName, and TypeOfPet. In most cases there are pets in every family, however, for some clients, there are no pets. What I'm trying to do is make the label PETS invisible if there are no pets, so the Label is not on the report by itself. How would I go about doing that?? Is this something I have to code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link shows how to hide the label if no data: https://forums.techguy.org/threads/solved-access-2003-hide-field-labels-on-reports-when-value-is-null.660825/

Below are the steps required:

```
1. Delete the label from the text box.
2. Add new text box in place of the old label.
3. Format the new text box same as other label.
4. Set it's "Can Shrink" property to "Yes".
5.Bind the 'new' label to an expression that will solve to "" if the [Pet] field is blank or to the text string "Pets:" if the [Pet] field is not blank.
6. Change text box Control Source field on the Data tab of the Properties window. In it put:
     iif(isnull([Pet]),"","Pets:")

This will put a zero-length string into the text box when the [Pet] field is null and the text "Pet:" when it is not null

7. If the field is blank, it could be null or a zero-length string (""), or could have any number of blank spaces in it. Rather than use "IsNull", use a combination of functions that will solve. i.e.:

Iif(trim(nz([Pet],""))="","","Pets:")
```